# Will the following scenario cause deadlock in PostgreSQL DB?

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark

I have two spark jobs, which try to update the same table at the same time. Will deadlock happen for the following scenarios?

1. Each updates different row;
2. Both update the same row but different columns;

Answer (score 2):

If you update a column, you update the whole row. A row is the granularity at which PostgreSQL locks.

Note that you cannot deadlock as long as both transactions update only a single row. A deadlock can happen if both transactions modify several rows, and modify the same rows in different order.

Comment: Thanks. So since row is the granularity for the lock, both mentioned scenarios will cause the lock.

Comment: Yes, but only if more than one row is affected by either transaction (which is not mentioned in your scenarios).